# How to place background image to the sides of container in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I place a background image, or (two), one at each side of Bootstrap .container, fixed so as the user scrolls on the container the images remain always visible.

I have been requested to place to images to the sides of a page that currently exists and is implemented with bootstrap with a structure similar to this:

```
<body>
  <div class="body-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Content</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>   
</body>
```

Since the page is using the **.container** class, the content is centered on the page with space to the right and left, the design team now wants to show an image to each side, fixed as the content is scrolled.

Following a structure similar to this image:

[image]

I can not simply change the structure in the **.container**, lets say dividing it in **.col-md-1**, **col-md-10**, **col-md-1**, because they want the images to be visible only if there is enough space, they want the content to take the full space of .container as it is taking now.

I have tried different things, so far I manage to place a background image, but it overflows outside the page and the right side is not visible.

Due to copyright issues I can't show the actual images they want to use, however I found something similar on internet, you can see an example here on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dzyann/Ljt1o0r1/21/). The left side is visible, but the right side is outside the page. Maybe I need to divide the image in two?

Answer (score -3):

Luckily, your problem is very easy to solve. Take a look at the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/6zjtgxdm/) to see how to give a div background with the the background-image tag. Relevant css below.

```
div {
  background-image : url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/11/11/article-2500617-007F32C500000258-970_306x423.jpg");
}
```

Just add

```
overflow-y:auto
```

if you want to add scrolling to any div